# Updating Vuex following Drag and Drop using vuedraggable

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, vuedraggable

I have created a Vue application that uses Vuetify, Vuex and vuedraggable.  The component functions as expected with drag and drop of v-card containing the associated information but I have not been able to find a way to identify the destination so that I can update the Vuex Store

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row justify='center'>
      <v-col v-for="stage in stages" :key="stage.value">
        <span class="card-text-bold">{{ stage.heading }}</span>
        <draggable :list="buckets[stage.name]" group="openTasks" :move="handleStatus">
          <v-card color="commentCard" class="list-group mt-3" v-for="task in buckets[stage.name]" :key="task._id">
            <v-card-text>

              <span class="card-text-bold">{{ task.title}}</span>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-text>
              <span class="card-text"> {{ task.description}} </span>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-text>
              {{ task.assignee}}<v-icon right @click="goToTask(task._id)">edit</v-icon>
            </v-card-text>

          </v-card>
        </draggable>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  name: 'Tasks',

  components: {
    draggable
  },

  data() {
    return {
      stages: [
        { heading: 'Created', name: 'created' },
        { heading: 'Assigned', name: 'assigned' },
        { heading: 'In Progress', name: 'in progress' },
        { heading: 'On Hold', name: 'on hold' },
        { heading: 'Complete', name: 'complete' },
        { heading: 'Closed', name: 'closed' }
      ]
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.handleGetTasks();
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['user', 'loading', 'tasks', 'buckets'])
  },

  methods: {
    getTimeFromNow(time) {
      return moment(new Date(time)).fromNow();
    },
    goToTask(taskId) {
      this.$router.push(`/task/${taskId}`);
    },

    handleGetTasks() {
      const userRole = localStorage.getItem('role');
      const fullname = localStorage.getItem('fullname');

      switch (userRole) {
        case 'Manager': {
          this.$store.dispatch('getAllTasks');
          break;
        }

        case 'Requester': {
          this.$store.dispatch('getRequestTasks', {
            fullname: fullname
          });
          break;
        }

        case 'Assignee': {
          this.$store.dispatch('getAssignTasks', {
            fullname: fullname
          });

          break;
        }
      }
    },

    stateTasks(target) {
      console.log('state', target);
      if (this.buckets[target] > 0) return this.buckets[target];
      else return [];
    },

    handleStatus(evt) {
      const movedId = evt.draggedContext.element._id;
      var targetStage;

      console.log('source', movedId, 'target', Object.keys(evt.relatedContext.list));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The source list for data used here is the 'buckets' object which contains an array of tasks for each of the task stages. Drag and Drop moves the task cards from the source to the target but I have been able to find a way to identify the target list.

Please provide advice about how I can determine which of the lists in the 'buckets' object should be updated following the move.

Thanks

Des

Comment: in cases like this, it's way easier to get help if you create a codepen/jsbin/etc working example...

Comment: This is not a 'coding' problem that can be easily reproduced in codepen. It primarily relates to the vuedraggable package and therefore could only be answered by someone with experience implementing a similar app.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the documentation, you'll see that vuedraggable has a @end event which will trigger after moving an element. When logging that event you'll notice quite a lot of useful information - such as oldIndex, newIndex and more..

```
<draggable :list="list" @end="onEnd">
```

Source: https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#events

Comment: There is indeed a lot of information returned by @end but I am not able to find anything that identifies the target list. My application uses a list for each project stage so that tasks can be moved between lists.  The only way I have been able to find the target is by iterating through the tasks in each list to find the task that does not match the list.  This solves the problem but it seems like a brute force solution. I am looking for some way to identify the target list from the drag event

Comment: It would be really awesome if you could provide a codesandbox so we are all on the same page on how your app behaves. I feel like I got the gist of what you're trying to do but I'd really like to try a thing or two, thus my previous answer being somewhat generic. I cannot remember all the properties returned by @end but I'm pretty sure there was a target element. You might provide some sort of identifier-property in the markup so you can easily recognize the item without having to iterate through all of them again. Not sure if that's viable in your scenario. Again, please provide a codesandbox

Comment: I did try the idea of adding a class to each v-col then searching the element but I don't have enough experience to find that identifier in the element.  I have not previously created a sandbox or codepen so I should learn how to do that

Comment: It's basically your editor but in a browser :) super convenient. just give it a shot. It really isn't as intimidating as it might seem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by parsing the HTML element of the move event.

The header for each of the stage columns can then be used as the identifier of the target list.

Here is the code

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row justify='center'>
      <v-col v-for="(stage, index) in stages" :key='index'>

        <draggable :list="buckets[stage]" group="openTasks" :move='handleMove'>
          <span slot="header" :tag="stage" class="card-text-bold">{{ stage }}</span>
          <v-card color="commentCard" class="list-group mt-3" v-for="task in buckets[stage]" :key="task._id">
            <v-card-text>

              <span class="card-text-bold">{{ task.title}}</span>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-text>
              <span class="card-text"> {{ task.description}} </span>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-text>
              {{ task.assignee}}<v-icon right @click="goToTask(task._id)">edit</v-icon>
            </v-card-text>

          </v-card>
        </draggable>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  name: 'Tasks',

  components: {
    draggable
  },

  data() {
    return {
      stages: ['created', 'assigned', 'in progress', 'on hold', 'complete', 'archive']
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.handleGetTasks();
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['user', 'loading', 'tasks', 'buckets'])
  },

  methods: {
    getTimeFromNow(time) {
      return moment(new Date(time)).fromNow();
    },
    goToTask(taskId) {
      this.$router.push(`/task/${taskId}`);
    },

    handleGetTasks() {
      const userRole = localStorage.getItem('role');
      const fullname = localStorage.getItem('fullname');

      switch (userRole) {
        case 'Manager': {
          this.$store.dispatch('getAllTasks');
          break;
        }

        case 'Requester': {
          this.$store.dispatch('getRequestTasks', {
            fullname: fullname
          });
          break;
        }

        case 'Assignee': {
          this.$store.dispatch('getAssignTasks', {
            fullname: fullname
          });

          break;
        }
      }
    },

    handleMove(evt) {
      const movedId = evt.draggedContext.element._id;
      var stageTag = evt.relatedContext.component.rootContainer.firstElementChild.innerText;
      if (this.stages.includes(stageTag)) {
        this.$store.dispatch('changeStatus', {
          taskId: movedId,
          status: stageTag
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Decoding the component HTML is done with this

```
evt.relatedContext.component.rootContainer.firstElementChild.innerText;
```